# Yesod: -dump-splices reliability

Tags: haskell, ghc, yesod

I'm using ghc parameter `-dump-splices` to see the static file names generated by Yesod while debugging.

But I have found that sometimes it displays the static files name ( eg: `css_bootstrap_css`) but most of the times it doesn't show any of the static files.

Am I doing something wrong here?

I'm attaching the dump file [here.](http://pastebin.com/JtAtbNPP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this should solve the issue:

```
touch Settings/StaticFiles.hs
```

Or even a cabal configure and build seems to work.